# Including current value from historical data with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my application I have Cars, Users, and a join table describing car ownership. I need to be able to determine who has owned a car at a specific point in time. However, the most common use case (over 90% of usage) is that I need to know the current owner, and I want to make that as simple as possible. Here are my tables:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwnerHistory {get; set;}
    public virtual User CurrentOwner {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwnerHistory {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Car> CurrentCars {get; set;}
}

public class CarOwner
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CarId {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public DateTime OwnershipStartedAt {get; set;}

    public virtual Car Car {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

I was considering making CurrentOwner and CurrentCars as not-mapped properties and possibly some extension method to "include" them, but I'm not sure if and how that could be done with EF. I would like to call it like

```
var user = dbContext.Set<User>().IncludeCurrentOwner().First(x => x.Id == [my user id]);
```

The logic for joining the current owner should be to pick CarOwner which has largest OwnershipChangedAt.

Alteratively there could be some extension method that would filter the CarOwnerHistory:

```
var user = dbContext.Set<User>()
    .Include(x => x.CarOwnerHistory
        .Where(y => y.OwnershipChangeDate == x.CarOwnerHistory.Select(z => z.OwnershipChangeDate).Max())
    )
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Car)
    .First(x => x.Id == [my user id]);
```

So here are my questions:

1. How could I create extension methods to include CurrentOwner and CurrentCars?
2. Is there some alternative method to achieve the same thing, e.g. by declaring some custom rule in DbContext to include a not-mapped property?

Comment: So, your project do not use DTO classes? Via `Select` you can project anything without any additional relationships.

Comment: Sure I can project the results. But that means that I have to get the whole owner history from the database even if I only need the current owner.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? / Look at [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16), [temporal tables in EF Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep only CarOwnerHistory in user. All needed data cen be retrieved via `Select`

```cs
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwnerHistory {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwnerHistory {get; set;}
}

public class CarOwner
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CarId {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}

    public DateTime OwnershipStartedAt {get; set;}
    public DateTime? OwnershipEndAt {get; set;}

    public virtual Car Car {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

You can project all needed data via Select. For sure anonymous calsses should be DTO clasess.

```cs
var userCarsWithHisotry = dbContext.Set<User>()
    .Where(u => u.Id == [my user id])
    .AsSplitQuery() // for performance
    .Select(u => new 
    {
        User = u,
        CurrentCars = u.CarOwnerHistory
            .Where(oh => u.OwnershipEndAt == null)
            .Select(oh => oh.Car)
            .ToList(),

        CarHistory = u.CarOwnerHistory.ToList()
    })
    .First();
```